# Internal padding for JTextArea with background Image

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

My ultimate goal is to have a `JTextArea` with a background image. I found code online that showed me how to do this, but now I'm having an issue with the text being on top of the image.

This Is what I mean:

[image: Text overlapping image]

Is there any way I can add a sort of inward indent so that the text is not overlapping the edges of the image?

---

Here is the raw comment bubble image.

[image: Comment bubble]

---

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.GrayFilter;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class myBackgroundSample {

    String file;

    public myBackgroundSample(String i) {
        file = i;
        setItUp();
    }

    public void setItUp() {
        final ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(file);
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea() {
            Image image = imageIcon.getImage();

            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                setOpaque(false);
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Background Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        content.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String right = "chat1.jpg";
        myBackgroundSample temp = new myBackgroundSample(right);

    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the image for chat1:
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-uhDR71VGYfA/TuRNiM2DfOI/AAAAAAAAADU/DqOuEi8c3lg/s334/chat1.jpg

Comment: 1) Why a `JTextArea` (as opposed to a `JLabel` or other syled component)? 2) I think this would best be done with a **custom** border, a `CommentBubbleBorder`. 3)  Swing components should override `paintComponent(Graphics)`, rather than `paint(Graphics)`.

Comment: Is it not about time you select an answer to some of your [earlier questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1091968/user1091968?tab=questions)?

Answer (score 12):

Use a custom border that extends [`AbstractBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/AbstractBorder.html).  Something like this:

[image: Text Bubble Border]

Getting the exact shape & color is left as an exercise for the reader. :)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;

class TextBubbleBorder extends AbstractBorder {

    private Color color;
    private int thickness = 4;
    private int radii = 8;
    private int pointerSize = 7;
    private Insets insets = null;
    private BasicStroke stroke = null;
    private int strokePad;
    private int pointerPad = 4;
    RenderingHints hints;

    TextBubbleBorder(
        Color color) {
            new TextBubbleBorder(color, 4, 8, 7);
    }

    TextBubbleBorder(
        Color color, int thickness, int radii, int pointerSize) {
            this.thickness = thickness;
            this.radii = radii;
            this.pointerSize = pointerSize;
        this.color = color;

        stroke = new BasicStroke(thickness);
        strokePad = thickness/2;

        hints = new RenderingHints(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int pad = radii + strokePad;
        int bottomPad = pad + pointerSize + strokePad;
        insets = new Insets(pad,pad,bottomPad,pad);
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return insets;
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets) {
        return getBorderInsets(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(
        Component c,
        Graphics g,
        int x, int y,
        int width, int height) {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        int bottomLineY = height-thickness-pointerSize;

        RoundRectangle2D.Double bubble = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(
            0+strokePad,
            0+strokePad,
            width-thickness,
            bottomLineY,
            radii,
            radii
            );

        Polygon pointer = new Polygon();

        // left point
        pointer.addPoint(
            strokePad+radii+pointerPad,
            bottomLineY);
        // right point
        pointer.addPoint(
            strokePad+radii+pointerPad+pointerSize,
            bottomLineY);
        // bottom point
        pointer.addPoint(
            strokePad+radii+pointerPad+(pointerSize/2),
            height-strokePad);

        Area area = new Area(bubble);
        area.add(new Area(pointer));

        g2.setRenderingHints(hints);

        Area spareSpace = new Area(new Rectangle(0,0,width,height));
        spareSpace.subtract(area);
        g2.setClip(spareSpace);
        g2.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
        g2.setClip(null);

        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.setStroke(stroke);
        g2.draw(area);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JLabel l = new JLabel(
                    "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog!");

                l.setBorder(new TextBubbleBorder(Color.MAGENTA.darker(),2,4,0));
                l.setOpaque(true);
                l.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, l);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! A couple questions:
What is the little "i" bubble to left?
What portion of this code can be edited so that the words will wrap around instead of stretching the text area?
" so that the conversation bubble is stemming from the right?
My overall goal is to simulate conversation view for chat.

Comment: See further info. (and a repeated question) in edit to answer.

Answer (score 6):

You should use an `Border` for that, more specifictly you should use [`BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(int top, int left, int bottom, int right)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createEmptyBorder%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29):

```
textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,15,10));
```

You should also override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`. Also, use `setRows()` and `setColumns()` to set the size of the textArea, then you can use `pack()` instead of `setSize(400,400)` which is not recommended. See this example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class Test extends JFrame {

    class MyTextArea extends JTextArea {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2.setColor(Color.PINK);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
            g2.drawRoundRect(3, 3, getWidth()-7, getHeight()-7, 5, 5);
        }

    }

    public Test() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JTextArea textArea = new MyTextArea();
        textArea.setRows(3);
        textArea.setColumns(25);
        textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        panel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        add(panel);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice example, but I still think a [custom border](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8463742/418556) is the way to go on this one. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: You are right. It depends how much changes he wants to do. This single line fix may help, but not be the best solution. +1 for your solution.

Comment: +1. easiest solution for those of use that are Graphics challenged :)

Comment: Thank you!
I'm working with this particular line of code:
textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
...to create a border so it looks like the text is confined within the bubble image.

Answer (score 1):

[To post code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), indent every line by four spaces.

I assume you are overriding `paintComponent()`* for your `JTextArea`. If you are, make sure that it is transparent by adding

```
setOpaque(false);
```

*This also works if you override `paint()`, but as trashgod correctly states, that would interfere with `paintBorder()`.

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

A better version of TextBubbleBorder.

https://gist.github.com/wenerme/6940534

- pointer padding control
- pointer side control
- dynamic change