# How to make 3D rounded corner JLabel in Java?

Tags: java, swing, border, jlabel, paintcomponent

I know there is a way to extend a JLabel to paint 3D borders and a way to paint round borders, but how do you get both? Here is my code

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     g.setColor(getBackground());
     g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, 25, 25);
     g.fill3DRect(10, 10, 30, 30, true);
     super.paintComponent(g);
```

Comment: does your code not work? what does it show?

Comment: You will have more success with `JLabel.setBorder()` as shown in an answer below than with overriding `paintComponent()`, because if you use `setBorder()` then the panel may adjust its size in its container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`LineBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/LineBorder.html) with rounded corners or a variant of the [`TextBubbleBorder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8463742/418556).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You refer this code to create Round Corner JLabel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class RoundedLineBorder extends JPanel {

    public RoundedLineBorder() {
        super(true);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Rounded Corners");

        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

    LineBorder line = new LineBorder(Color.blue, 2, true);

        label.setBorder(line);

        add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rounded Line Border");
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setSize(500, 200);
         frame.setContentPane(new RoundedLineBorder());
         frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```