# How to create rounded corner BevelBorder in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, border

I want to use a Bevel Border because it is sort of 3D but I don't know how to create a rounded corner BevelBorder.

SoftBevelBorder does not work because the rounded radius is too small. How to make the corners more round?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internal padding for JTextArea with background Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462414/internal-padding-for-jtextarea-with-background-image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here there is an example of rounded border, where you can adjust the radius:

http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/rounded-border-for-jtextfield.html

Not bevel, but you can see how to achieve the "bevelness" in the source code of SoftBevelBorder.
If you manage to do it, I would be interested in the code :)

Comment: I know its a few years later but if your still interested see my answer

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the correct border shape you need to override the [`AbstractBorder.paintBorder(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/border/AbstractBorder.html#paintBorder-java.awt.Component-java.awt.Graphics-int-int-int-int-) method. When you do that you can add code similar to this to the method.

```
super.paintBorder(c, g, x, y, width, height);

Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.setRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));

Shape clip = g2d.getClip();
Area rect = new Area(clip);
rect.subtract(new Area(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height, radii, radii)));
g2d.setClip(rect);
g2d.setColor(c.getParent().getBackground());
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
g2d.setClip(clip);
g2d.draw(rect);
```

Now there are two main ways you can draw a bevel effect around the border but depending on the complexity you want the bevel to be, depends on which way you use. For a simple bevel border that uses 2 colours, you can use something similar to this.

```
g2d.setColor(inner); //Inner Rectangle
g2d.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x + 1, y + 1, width - 2, height - 2, radii, radii));

g2d.setColor(outer); //Outer Rectangle
g2d.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, width - 2, height - 2, radii, radii));
```

However, if you want to use a more complex bevel border that uses 4 different colours, you will need to look at the source code of [`javax.swing.border.BevelBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/border/BevelBorder.html). This will show you that you need a piece of code similar to this.

```
double offset = radii / 2;
//Outer
g2d.setColor(outerH);
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, offset, 0, height - 2 - offset)); //Left
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(1 + offset, 0, width - 2 - offset, 0)); //Top
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 1, 0, radii, radii, 0, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Right
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(0, 0, radii, radii, 90, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Left

//Inner
g2d.setColor(innerH);
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(1, 1 + offset, 1, height - 3 - offset)); //Left
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(2 + offset, 1, width - 3 - offset, 1)); //Top
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 2, 1, radii, radii, 0, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Right
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(1, 1, radii, radii, 90, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Left

//Outer
g2d.setColor(outer);
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(offset, height - 1, width - 1 - offset, height - 1)); //Bottom
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(width - 1, offset, width - 1, height - 2 - offset)); //Right
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 1, height - radii - 1, radii, radii, 270, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Right
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(0, height - radii - 1, radii, radii, 180, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Left

//Inner
g2d.setColor(inner);
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(1 + offset, height - 2, width - 2 - offset, height - 2)); //Bottom
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(width - 2, 1 + offset, width - 2, height - 3 - offset)); //Right
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 2, height - radii - 2, radii, radii, 270, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Right
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(1, height - radii - 2, radii, radii, 180, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Left
```

You may also use the following code if it is important for the color to stop half way around the corner.

```
double offset = radii / 2;
//Outer
g2d.setColor(outerH);
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, offset, 0, height - 2 - offset)); //Left
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(1 + offset, 0, width - 2 - offset, 0)); //Top
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 1, 0, radii, radii, 45, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Right P1
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(0, 0, radii, radii, 90, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Left
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(0, height - radii - 1, radii, radii, 180, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Left P1

//Inner
g2d.setColor(innerH);
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(1, 1 + offset, 1, height - 3 - offset)); //Left
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(2 + offset, 1, width - 3 - offset, 1)); //Top
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 2, 1, radii, radii, 45, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Right P1
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(1, 1, radii, radii, 90, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Left
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(1, height - radii - 2, radii, radii, 180, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Left P1

//Outer
g2d.setColor(outerS);
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(offset, height - 1, width - 1 - offset, height - 1)); //Bottom
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(width - 1, offset, width - 1, height - 2 - offset)); //Right
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 1, 0, radii, radii, 0, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Right P2
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 1, height - radii - 1, radii, radii, 270, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Right
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(0, height - radii - 1, radii, radii, 225, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Left P2

//Inner
g2d.setColor(innerS);
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(1 + offset, height - 2, width - 2 - offset, height - 2)); //Bottom
g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(width - 2, 1 + offset, width - 2, height - 3 - offset)); //Right
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 2, 1, radii, radii, 0, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Right P2
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 2, height - radii - 2, radii, radii, 270, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Right
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(1, height - radii - 2, radii, radii, 225, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Left P2
```

When we put all this together you get a class that looks like this.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class RoundedBorder extends AbstractBorder {
    private int radii;
    private Insets insets;
    private Color innerS = new Color(166, 166, 166);
    private Color outerS = new Color(116, 116, 116);
    private Color innerH = Color.WHITE; 
    private Color outerH = Color.WHITE;
    private boolean tColor = false;

    public RoundedBorder(int radius) {
        radii = radius;
    }

    public RoundedBorder(int radius, Insets i) {
        radii = radius;
        insets = i;
    }

    public RoundedBorder(int radius, Insets i, Color out, Color in) {
        radii = radius;
        insets = i;
        innerS = in;
        outerS = out;
        tColor = true;
    }

    public RoundedBorder(int radius, Insets i, Color outH, Color inH, Color outS, Color inS) {
        radii = radius;
        insets = i;
        innerS = inS;
        outerS = outS;
        innerH = inH;
        outerH = outH;
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        if(insets != null) {
            return insets;
        }
        return new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets) {
        return getBorderInsets(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super.paintBorder(c, g, x, y, width, height);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));

        Shape clip = g2d.getClip();
        Area rect = new Area(clip);
        rect.subtract(new Area(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height, radii, radii)));
        g2d.setClip(rect);
        g2d.setColor(c.getParent().getBackground());
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g2d.setClip(clip);
        g2d.draw(rect);

        if(!tColor) {
            double offset = radii / 2;
            //Outer
            g2d.setColor(outerH);
            g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, offset, 0, height - 2 - offset)); //Left
            g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(1 + offset, 0, width - 2 - offset, 0)); //Top
            g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 1, 0, radii, radii, 45, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Right P1
            g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(0, 0, radii, radii, 90, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Left
            g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(0, height - radii - 1, radii, radii, 180, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Left P1

            //Inner
            g2d.setColor(innerH);
            g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(1, 1 + offset, 1, height - 3 - offset)); //Left
            g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(2 + offset, 1, width - 3 - offset, 1)); //Top
            g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 2, 1, radii, radii, 45, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Right P1
            g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(1, 1, radii, radii, 90, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Left
            g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(1, height - radii - 2, radii, radii, 180, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Left P1

            //Outer
            g2d.setColor(outerS);
            g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(offset, height - 1, width - 1 - offset, height - 1)); //Bottom
            g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(width - 1, offset, width - 1, height - 2 - offset)); //Right
            g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 1, 0, radii, radii, 0, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Right P2
            g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 1, height - radii - 1, radii, radii, 270, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Right
            g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(0, height - radii - 1, radii, radii, 225, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Left P2

            //Inner
            g2d.setColor(innerS);
            g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(1 + offset, height - 2, width - 2 - offset, height - 2)); //Bottom
            g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(width - 2, 1 + offset, width - 2, height - 3 - offset)); //Right
            g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 2, 1, radii, radii, 0, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Top Right P2
            g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(width - radii - 2, height - radii - 2, radii, radii, 270, 90, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Right
            g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(1, height - radii - 2, radii, radii, 225, 45, Arc2D.OPEN)); //Bottom Left P2
        } else {
            g2d.setColor(innerS); //Inner Rectangle
            g2d.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x + 1, y + 1, width - 2, height - 2, radii, radii));

            g2d.setColor(outerS); //Outer Rectangle
            g2d.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, width - 2, height - 2, radii, radii));
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can implement this class on your component by just doing `yourComponent.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(10));` or by using one of the other constructors for the `RoundedBorder` class.

Comment: I tried it, and it does look rounded, but not bevelled, at least not in a way that is similar to BevelBorder...

Comment: @lbalazscs Thank you for your feedback. I should have tried it with the initial bevel border colours before posting. I have edited the code so that when you use `yourComponent.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(10));` it will look a lot more "bevelly" (pretty sure that's not a word :P) by default

Comment: @lbalazscs Would you say it looks better or should I change it somehow?

Comment: It's much better now, much more "bevelly" :) This should be the accepted answer, not mine.

Comment: @lbalazscs I'm happy with it being yours as I got the idea from your answer. I just implemented it :) Again thanks for the feedback

Comment: Thank you, very well written and versatile class.