# What do I need to do to replicate this component with gradient paint?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, gradient, paintcomponent

I attempted to replicate this component (at the bottom of the post), but I can't seem to get it to look nice.

[image]

So I'm wondering, how do I replicate this gradient paint? Or if it isn't the gradient paint, what do I do to get similar results?

My attempt turned out very flat black compared to this component. Also it had the JFrame options (close, minimize, etc) and it didn't have a 'rounded' look to the components. I'm looking for someone who can improve what I have and explain where I went wrong. I know I can simply use an already made Look and Feel, but I would like to get my example project as close as possible to the BitDefender GUI in the image excluding the text. (I can provide code if need be)

Also notice I skipped the panel between Background and the 'Virus Shield', 'Auto Scan', 'My BitDefender' panels. I did this mainly because I wanted to keep my SSCCE as small as possible.

Also I want to note that setting the insets to `gbc.insets = new Insets(2,10,2,10);` on the 3 `TopPanels` makes it look much closer to the spacing of the BitDefender GUI. (I just didn't have the time to upload the picture at the moment. So I left the code as is, but I do realize that it can be updated to the above insets.

[image]

**Edit - Updated with more source**

Here is my code / SSCCE (it is 3 separate classes, but I consilidated them into one .java)

```
package testgui;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class TestGui {

    public TestGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        MidPanel midPanel = new MidPanel();
        TopPanel topPanel1 = new TopPanel();
        TopPanel topPanel2 = new TopPanel();
        TopPanel topPanel3 = new TopPanel();
        JLabel appName = new JLabel("MyApplication");
        JLabel verNum = new JLabel("version 1.0");
        Font verFont = new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11);
        Font nameFont = new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        appName.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        appName.setFont(nameFont);
        verNum.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        verNum.setFont(verFont);

        //add program name and version number
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        midPanel.add(appName, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        midPanel.add(verNum, gbc);

        //add 3 example top panels to midpanel
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1,2,1,2);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        midPanel.add(topPanel1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1,2,1,2);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        midPanel.add(topPanel2, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1,2,1,2);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        midPanel.add(topPanel3, gbc);

        //add panel to push other panels to top
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        JPanel invisPanel = new JPanel();
        invisPanel.setOpaque(false);
        midPanel.add(invisPanel, gbc);

        frame.getContentPane().add(midPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //test it out
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGui();
    }

    //class for the top 3 panels
    private class TopPanel extends JPanel {

        private int maxLength;
        private boolean cyclic;


        public TopPanel() {
            initComponents();
            setOpaque(false);
            cyclic = true;
            maxLength = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if(isOpaque()) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                return;
            }

            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            GradientPaint paint = null;

            Color top = new Color(50, 50, 50);
            Color btm = new Color(19, 19, 19);

            paint = new GradientPaint(width / 2, 0, top, width / 2, maxLength > 0 ? maxLength : height, btm, cyclic);

            if(paint == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid direction specified in GamerTagPanel");
            }

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            Paint oldPaint = g2d.getPaint();
            g2d.setPaint(paint);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            g2d.setPaint(oldPaint);
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 200);  
        }

        private void initComponents() {
            GridBagConstraints gbc;
            JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
            JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel();

            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(204,204,204)));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            jLabel1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
            jLabel1.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            jLabel1.setText("Scanning...");
            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            add(jLabel1, gbc);

            jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11)); 
            jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
            jLabel2.setText("C:\\Directory\\Folder\\SubFolder\\SpecificFolder\\File.file");
            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
            gbc.weightx = 1.0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            add(jLabel2, gbc);
        }
    }

    public class MidPanel extends JPanel {

        private int maxLength;
        private boolean cyclic;

        public MidPanel() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setOpaque(false);
            maxLength = 0;
            cyclic = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if(isOpaque()) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                return;
            }

            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            GradientPaint paint = null;

            Color top = new Color(75, 75, 75);
            Color btm = new Color(19, 19, 19);

            paint = new GradientPaint(width / 2, 0, top, width / 2, maxLength > 0 ? maxLength : height, btm, cyclic);

            if(paint == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid direction specified in GamerTagPanel");
            }

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            Paint oldPaint = g2d.getPaint();
            g2d.setPaint(paint);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            g2d.setPaint(oldPaint);
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 400);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks JoopEggen for pointing out my issue with colors on the GradientPaint. It helped out quite a bit. I'm still looking for someone to put together a better/closer looking example. This is my first go at overriding the paintComponent in such a way.

Comment: _I can provide code if need be_ please post it.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I edited it with my `paintComponent()`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE. The matter of whether the gradient is as expected could be easier sorted by drawing it to a 'BufferedImage'.

Comment: The difference between color component 19 and 27 cannot really be recognized, "black" reaches from 0 upto 80 (IMHO). Try 19 and 90.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks for that information, 50 seems to come relatively close for the outermost panels. 75 seems to be close for the middle panel. I still have issues with the line border though. Any suggestions for that line border? My assumption is its a dark grey 1px line border.

Comment: @WilliamShatner sorry, not my forte B).

Comment: @AndrewThompson & everyone else I added my SSCCE and a picture of my current outcome. Hopefully that helps in getting some responses :)

Comment: Now that I look really closely at the first image, I don't think they use gradients of colors at all, just slightly different colors between the foreground panels and background (parent) panel.  And as an aside, I think your current gradients/colors look better.  I'm just sayin'..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's do some reverse engineering first. Several simplifications can be maid during that process. Moreover, I would say it is also possible to enhance that application look, because first impression is far from being very positive.

[image]

Basically the following elements can be found behind that design:

- gradients
- properly selected colors
- rounded corners
- outlines

[image]

Please note, rounded corners, outlines are important. BTW, some gradients can be optimized to provide clean and simple design. Please check [The Battle Between Flat Design And Skeuomorphism](http://sachagreif.com/flat-pixels/) for additional motivation.

Your example was modified and looks like the following (it just a visual result):

[image]

I've used the following colors:

[image]

Code:

```java
public class TestGui {

    public TestGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MidPanel midPanel = new MidPanel();
        TopPanel topPanel1 = new TopPanel();
        TopPanel topPanel2 = new TopPanel();
        TopPanel topPanel3 = new TopPanel();

        JLabel appName = new JLabel("MyApplication");
        JLabel verNum = new JLabel("version 1.0");
        Font verFont = new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11);
        Font nameFont = new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        appName.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        appName.setFont(nameFont);
        verNum.setForeground(new Color(0xFF9f9f9f));
        verNum.setFont(verFont);

        //add program name and version number
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        midPanel.add(appName, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        midPanel.add(verNum, gbc);

        //add 3 example top panels to midpanel
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1,2,1,2);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        midPanel.add(topPanel1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1,2,1,2);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        midPanel.add(topPanel2, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1,2,1,2);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        midPanel.add(topPanel3, gbc);

        //add panel to push other panels to top
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        JPanel invisPanel = new JPanel();
        invisPanel.setOpaque(false);
        midPanel.add(invisPanel, gbc);

        frame.getContentPane().add(midPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //test it out
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGui();
    }

    //class for the top 3 panels
    private class TopPanel extends JPanel {

        private int maxLength;
        private boolean cyclic;


        public TopPanel() {
            super(true);
            initComponents();
            setOpaque(false);
            cyclic = true;
            maxLength = 0;
        }


        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if(isOpaque()) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                return;
            }

            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            GradientPaint paint = null;

            //Color top = new Color(50, 50, 50);
            //Color btm = new Color(19, 19, 19);

            Color top = new Color(0xFF222222);
            Color btm = new Color(0xFF0c0c0c);

            paint = new GradientPaint(width / 2, 0, top, width / 2, maxLength > 0 ? maxLength : height, btm, cyclic);

            if(paint == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid direction specified in GamerTagPanel");
            }

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            Paint oldPaint = g2d.getPaint();
            g2d.setPaint(paint);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            g2d.setPaint(oldPaint);

            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
            Dimension d = getSize();

            g.setColor(new Color(0xFF484848));
            g.drawRoundRect(1, 1, d.width-3, d.height-3, 10, 10);

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, d.width-1, d.height-1, 10, 10);
        }        

        private void initComponents() {
            GridBagConstraints gbc;
            JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
            JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel();

            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(204,204,204)));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            jLabel1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
            jLabel1.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            jLabel1.setText("Scanning...");
            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            add(jLabel1, gbc);

            jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
            jLabel2.setForeground(new Color(0xFF9f9f9f));
            jLabel2.setText("C:\\Directory\\Folder\\SubFolder\\SpecificFolder\\File.file");
            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
            gbc.weightx = 1.0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            add(jLabel2, gbc);
        }
    }

    public class MidPanel extends JPanel {

        private int maxLength;
        private boolean cyclic;

        public MidPanel() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setOpaque(false);
            maxLength = 0;
            cyclic = false;
        }


//        public void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
//            g.setColor(Color.RED);
//            Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
//            g.drawRoundRect(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height, 10, 10);
//        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if(isOpaque()) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                return;
            }

            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            GradientPaint paint = null;

            Color top = new Color(0xFF282828);
            Color btm = new Color(0xFF0e0e0e);

            paint = new GradientPaint(width / 2, 0, top, width / 2, maxLength > 0 ? maxLength : height, btm, cyclic);

            if(paint == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid direction specified in GamerTagPanel");
            }

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            Paint oldPaint = g2d.getPaint();
            g2d.setPaint(paint);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            g2d.setPaint(oldPaint);
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 400);
        }
    }
}
```

**Best way to implement this UI**

I think the only correct approach is to implement new Look&Feel subset. Take a look on [project seaglass](http://code.google.com/p/seaglass/):

[image]

**What did I use**

All these examples were prepared using [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) -- an Open Source vector graphics editor.
You can download my [SVG source](http://renat.in.ua/web/stackoverflow/application-replica.svg)

Comment: Great breakdown! *Off topic* How did you break the BitDefender panels down like that? What software did you use? *On topic* I see you overroad the `drawBorder` method to get the rounded edges, how would you do something similar to rounding a JFrame (after setting it undecorated)?  -- Thanks for the interesting read about skeuomorphism. I'm going to check if I can add another bounty since you did a nice job breaking this down for me. **Edit** It is only allowing me to start a bounty of 200 on this post :/ perhaps I'll have to start a 100 on a different answer for you.

Comment: +1 @WilliamShatner: I _think_ you can add another bounty, but it can't less than the first. Edit: more [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Comment: Gentlemen, thank you very much, no need to start anything :) It is not about score, it is about fun and interesting answers. Please see updated answer with requested details.

Comment: After going through both of these answers, I feel your response more directly answers the question. I plan on reviewing some of you others answers and up-voting the ones that are helpful as well. I had considered using a look and feel, but many of them don't have the 'look' that I'm interested in. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

At a pinch, this is the best I can come up with.

[image: GradientPanels]

#### Notes:

1. As best I can tell, the line border color is 74,74,74.  I have used a rounded border, but it has smaller radius than shown in the original example.
2. The top color is brightened by the `offset` defined in code (mostly so I could **see** a difference!)  Reduce it to 0 for colors closer to what appear and to make the line more obvious.
3. The color of the text seems to be 249,249,249 (`#F9F9F9`) but I used `#B9B9B9` for the top text and white for the rest.

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

class GradientPanels {

    /** An 'offset' to make gradients more obvious. 
     * Reduce to 0 for more subtle effect.  */
    static final int o = 50;
    static final Color borderColor = new Color(74,74,74);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

                JPanel main = new GradientPanel(o + 40, 22);
                main.setLayout(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
                JLabel lTop = new JLabel("<html><body><h1 style='color: #B9B9B9'>Up<br>Here");
                main.add(lTop, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
                main.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

                JPanel center = new GradientPanel(o + 40, 17);
                AbstractBorder b = new CompoundBorder(
                        new LineBorder(borderColor, 1, true),
                        new EmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));
                center.setBorder(b);
                LayoutManager lm = new BoxLayout(center, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
                center.setLayout(lm);
                main.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                addPanel(center, "Virus Shield", o);
                center.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 10)));
                addPanel(center, "Auto Scan", o);
                center.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 10)));
                addPanel(center, "My BitDefender", o);
                center.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 50)));

                gui.add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }

    public static void addPanel(JPanel p, String text, int offset) {
        JPanel t = new GradientPanel(offset + 28, 20);
        AbstractBorder b = new CompoundBorder(
                new LineBorder(borderColor, 1, true),
                new EmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));
        t.setBorder(b);
        t.add(new JLabel("<html><body><h2 style='color: #FFFFFF'>" + text));

        p.add(t);
    }
}

class GradientPanel extends JPanel {

    Color top;
    Color btm;

    GradientPanel(int t, int b) {
        top = new Color(t, t, t);
        btm = new Color(b, b, b);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, top,
                0f, (float) getHeight(), btm);
        g2.setPaint(gp);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

---

### Edit 1

The border in my fist example is still far from that seen in the desired screenshot.  In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8463742/418556) I create a custom border with more rounded corners (a 'speech bubble').

[image: speech bubble]

Unfortunately that example works better for entirely transparent components like `JLabel`.  I've not had the time to look into adapting it for opaque components.

See [Border with rounded corners & transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15025092/418556) for further discussion.

Comment: Wow, you did a great job! I actually like your implementation much better than the BitDefender version. The only thing I would change would be setting the JFrame undecorated and rounding the frame, You even went to extra lengths to get the answer! I'll check in on this question and the one you linked to. (mKorbel's response with the link is gone so I didn't get to look at that). Much appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry for the second message, but I have a few questions (I can delete this when you're done answering): **1.** Is there any specific reason you chose `BoxLayout` over `GridBag`? **2.** Why a `JOptionPane` rather than `JFrame`? My assumption was just that this is an example, but if there are other reasons, I would love to hear them.

Comment: 1) *"Why `BoxLayout`?"*  Laziness.  I have never bothered to learn GBL properly, and could see this would fit a `BoxLayout` nicely.  2) *"Why option pane?"*  Laziness, again.  Once you have a GUI in a panel, it is just one line of code to show it on-screen in an option pane.  -- both justified by *"just that this is an example"*  ;)  BTW - No need for apologies.  It is healthy to question the strategies used in answers.  I included the context of your questions in my comment.  Leave your comment or delete it (whatever you think is best).

Comment: Oh, and glad you liked the result. :) Personally I was never that impressed with the BitDefender window - the gradients are so subtle I had to write a Java code to tell me the differences!  ;)

Comment: While I feel that Renat's response answers my question better; I feel that your response led me to realize that I agree with your opinion that the BitDefender GUI isn't as nice as I thought it was. I actually plan on using your example on my project (I'll probably make use of Renat's rounded panels on a separate part of it as well). Thanks Andrew for always being helpful!