# Label inside Circle

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, paintcomponent, drawstring

I want to put text ( must be formatted with HTML, so I can't use `drawString` in `PaintComponent`) inside Circle. Problem is that "`paintComponent`" is called after drawing label, so it covers my text.

How to draw oval at the beginning and then draw my String?

```
class Circle extends JLabel 
{

         public Circle(String string) {         super(string);  }
     @Override
    public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillOval(0,0, 70, 70);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
       g.drawOval(0,0, 70, 70); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: You might consider putting the label inside a custom border.  See [`TextBubbleBorder`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16909994/418556) for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the quickest solution is to change your `paintComponent` to

```
public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
{
  g.setColor(Color.yellow);
  g.fillOval(0,0, 70, 70);
  g.setColor(Color.blue);
  g.drawOval(0,0, 70, 70); 
  super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

I'd however also consider composition rather than inheritance in this case. Perhaps define another component class composed of the label and a panel with the circle.

Answer (score 1):

Consider putting the component inside a [custom border](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html#custom).  See [`TextBubbleBorder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16909994/418556) for ideas.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `setComponentZOrder()` to set the labels order to be higher up than the circle.