# How to set corner radius for line border?

Tags: java, swing, border

How to set arc width and height for line border. Since time, i have been using the method to create line borders in Java

```
BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,2,true);
```

But the problem is arc width and height are fixed. How could i increase this? Do i need to override `paintBorder()` for this?

Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: [maybe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15025092/714968) by @Andrew Thompson could be good start point, [I never need to solve that really](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/714968) deepth to with pixels precission, EDIT rest of ideas search in questions by (@mre)