# How to solve misalignment in boxlayout?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, alignment, boxlayout

I'm trying to add multiple Jlabels in a Jpanel with Box layout, But i'm facing prolems on setting their setAlignmentX() . I'm reffering to an example from this site of Text bubble border and trying to pull out some examples from it. The jpanel is then added in Jscrollpane.

My code is here !!!

```
//Source :Andrew Thompson

 class TextBubbleBorder extends AbstractBorder {
 private Color color;
 private int thickness = 4;
 private int radii = 8;
private int pointerSize = 7;
private Insets insets = null;
private BasicStroke stroke = null;
private int strokePad;
private int pointerPad = 4;
private boolean left = true;
RenderingHints hints;

TextBubbleBorder(
        Color color) {
    new TextBubbleBorder(color, 4, 8, 7);
}

TextBubbleBorder(
        Color color, int thickness, int radii, int pointerSize) {
    this.thickness = thickness;
    this.radii = radii;
    this.pointerSize = pointerSize;
    this.color = color;

    stroke = new BasicStroke(thickness);
    strokePad = thickness / 2;

    hints = new RenderingHints(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    int pad = radii + strokePad;
    int bottomPad = pad + pointerSize + strokePad;
    insets = new Insets(pad, pad, bottomPad, pad);
}

TextBubbleBorder(
        Color color, int thickness, int radii, int pointerSize, boolean left) {
    this(color, thickness, radii, pointerSize);
    this.left = left;
}

@Override
public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
    return insets;
}

@Override
public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets) {
    return getBorderInsets(c);
}

@Override
public void paintBorder(
        Component c,
        Graphics g,
        int x, int y,
        int width, int height) {

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    int bottomLineY = height - thickness - pointerSize;

    RoundRectangle2D.Double bubble = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(
            0 + strokePad,
            0 + strokePad,
            width - thickness,
            bottomLineY,
            radii,
            radii);

    Polygon pointer = new Polygon();

    if (left) {
        // left point
        pointer.addPoint(
                strokePad + radii + pointerPad,
                bottomLineY);
        // right point
        pointer.addPoint(
                strokePad + radii + pointerPad + pointerSize,
                bottomLineY);
        // bottom point
        pointer.addPoint(
                strokePad + radii + pointerPad + (pointerSize / 2),
                height - strokePad);
    } else {
        // left point
        pointer.addPoint(
                width - (strokePad + radii + pointerPad),
                bottomLineY);
        // right point
        pointer.addPoint(
                width - (strokePad + radii + pointerPad + pointerSize),
                bottomLineY);
        // bottom point
        pointer.addPoint(
                width - (strokePad + radii + pointerPad + (pointerSize / 2)),
                height - strokePad);
    }

    Area area = new Area(bubble);
    area.add(new Area(pointer));

    g2.setRenderingHints(hints);

    // Paint the BG color of the parent, everywhere outside the clip
    // of the text bubble.
    Component parent  = c.getParent();
    if (parent!=null) {
        Color bg = parent.getBackground();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,width, height);
        Area borderRegion = new Area(rect);
        borderRegion.subtract(area);
        g2.setClip(borderRegion);
        g2.setColor(bg);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g2.setClip(null);
    }

    g2.setColor(color);
    g2.setStroke(stroke);
    g2.draw(area);
}}

 //TextBubbleBorder ends here
```

Msgbox starts here

```
class msgbox extends JPanel {

    boolean ij = true;
    String msg = "";
    JLabel jl;

    msgbox() {
        //  msgpnl();
    }

    msgbox(String str, boolean bj) {
        ij = bj;
        msg = str;
        msgpnl();
    }
    /* public void setText(String str, boolean  bj){
     ij=bj;
     msg=str;
     msgpnl();
     }
     */

    public void msgpnl() {
        //setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        if (ij) {
            jl = new JLabel(msg);

            jl.setOpaque(true);
            jl.setBorder(new TextBubbleBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 1, 10, 7, ij));

            jl.setBackground(new Color(123, 104, 238));
            jl.setAlignmentX(0);
        } else {
            jl = new JLabel(msg, SwingConstants.RIGHT);

            jl.setOpaque(true);
            jl.setBorder(new TextBubbleBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 1, 10, 7, ij));

            jl.setBackground(new Color(224, 102, 255));
            jl.setAlignmentX(1);
        }
        this.add(jl);
        System.out.print("\nThis executed");
    }
}
```

chatpanel

```
class chatpanel extends JScrollPane {

    static JPanel jp;

    chatpanel() {
        this.setVisible(true);
        //this.setLayout(null);
        this.jp = new JPanel();
        this.jp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.jp, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        //jp= new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1,0,5));
        //this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        this.getViewport().add(jp);
        jp.setVisible(true);
        setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    }

    public void addmsg(Component co) {
        //msgscp.add(co);
        //co.setSize(100, 30);
        jp.add(co);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Testing msgpanel");
        jf.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
        chatpanel cp = new chatpanel();
        JButton jb = new JButton("new");
        msgbox mb;
        mb = new msgbox("<html><body style='width: 200px; padding: 5px;'>"
                + "<h1>Do U C Me?</h1>"
                + "Here is a long string that will wrap.  "
                + "The effect we want is a multi-line label.", true);
        // mb.setText();
        cp.addmsg(mb);
        msgbox mb2 = new msgbox("Hello 2", false);
        cp.addmsg(mb2);
        jb.setSize(100, 30);
        jf.add(cp);
        //jf.add(jb);
        jf.setSize(400, 400);
        //jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Plus i think i will face problem while wrapping up text in Jlabel, although i used HTML wrapping technique in chatpanel. that will not be effecient with changing sizes of msgboxes!! thanks in advance for help!!

Comment: didn't really read your code to any depth, so this might not be the problem, just: BoxLayout requires that all the children have the same alignment in the "other" direction (see the corresponding chapter in the tutorial referenced in the swing tag wiki) unrelated: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: btw: what _is_ the problem?

Comment: @kleopatra Apologies i'm new to java. i will keep that in my mind. The problem was while running chatpanel. Both msgboxes were misaligned. Now  again apologies i rechecked my code. that was problem with the values. in msgbox. But still one how to solve wrapping text problem in JLabel.

Comment: @kleopatra :-) nothing and nowhere, see my debugging tour (limited always upto 15 minutes)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image][image]

[only in due all my respect to @Andrew Thompson :-) and my curiosity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025092/border-with-rounded-corners-transparency)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class ChatPanel {

    private JFrame jf = new JFrame("Testing msgpanel");
    private JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
    private JPanel jp;
    private ChatPaneMsgBox mb;
    private ChatPaneMsgBox mb2;
    private JPanel cp = new JPanel();
    private JButton jb = new JButton("  ME !!! ");
    private JButton jb1 = new JButton("  YOU !!! ");

    public ChatPanel() {
        jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jp, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        mb = new ChatPaneMsgBox("<html><body style='width: 200px; padding: 5px;'>"
                + "<h1>Do U C Me?</h1>"
                + "Here is a long string that will wrap.  "
                + "The effect we want is a multi-line label.", true);
        addmsg(mb);
        mb2 = new ChatPaneMsgBox("Hello 2", false);
        addmsg(mb2);
        scroll.setViewportView(jp);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mb = new ChatPaneMsgBox("<html><body style='width: 200px; padding: 5px;'>"
                        + "<h1>Do U C Me?</h1>"
                        + "Here is a long string that will wrap.  "
                        + "The effect we want is a multi-line label.", true);
                addmsg(mb);
                Rectangle rect = jp.getBounds();
                Rectangle r2 = scroll.getViewport().getVisibleRect();
                jp.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle((int) rect.getWidth(), 
                        (int) rect.getHeight(), (int) r2.getWidth(), (int) r2.getHeight()));
            }
        });
        jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mb2 = new ChatPaneMsgBox("Hello 2", false);
                addmsg(mb2);
                Rectangle rect = jp.getBounds();
                Rectangle r2 = scroll.getViewport().getVisibleRect();
                jp.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle((int) rect.getWidth(), 
                        (int) rect.getHeight(), (int) r2.getWidth(), (int) r2.getHeight()));
            }
        });
        cp.add(jb);
        cp.add(jb1);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(scroll);
        jf.add(cp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        jf.setSize(400, 400);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addmsg(Component co) {
        jp.add(co);
        jp.revalidate();
        jp.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ChatPanel();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

class ChatPaneMsgBox extends JPanel {

    boolean ij = true;
    private String msg = "";
    private JLabel jl;

    public ChatPaneMsgBox() {
    }

    public ChatPaneMsgBox(String str, boolean bj) {
        ij = bj;
        msg = str;
        msgpnl();
    }

    private void msgpnl() {
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        if (ij) {
            jl = new JLabel(msg);

            jl.setOpaque(true);
            jl.setBorder(new TextBubbleBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 1, 10, 7, ij));

            jl.setBackground(new Color(123, 104, 238));
            jl.setAlignmentX(0);
        } else {
            jl = new JLabel(msg, SwingConstants.RIGHT);

            jl.setOpaque(true);
            jl.setBorder(new TextBubbleBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 1, 10, 7, ij));

            jl.setBackground(new Color(224, 102, 255));
            jl.setAlignmentX(1);
        }
        this.add(jl);
        System.out.print("\nThis executed");
    }
}
```

.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;

class TextBubbleBorder extends AbstractBorder {

    private Color color;
    private int thickness = 4;
    private int radii = 8;
    private int pointerSize = 7;
    private Insets insets = null;
    private BasicStroke stroke = null;
    private int strokePad;
    private int pointerPad = 4;
    private boolean left = true;
    RenderingHints hints;

    TextBubbleBorder(Color color) {
        new TextBubbleBorder(color, 4, 8, 7);
    }

    TextBubbleBorder(Color color, int thickness, int radii, int pointerSize) {
        this.thickness = thickness;
        this.radii = radii;
        this.pointerSize = pointerSize;
        this.color = color;
        stroke = new BasicStroke(thickness);
        strokePad = thickness / 2;
        hints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int pad = radii + strokePad;
        int bottomPad = pad + pointerSize + strokePad;
        insets = new Insets(pad, pad, bottomPad, pad);
    }

    TextBubbleBorder(Color color, int thickness, int radii, int pointerSize, boolean left) {
        this(color, thickness, radii, pointerSize);
        this.left = left;
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return insets;
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets) {
        return getBorderInsets(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        int bottomLineY = height - thickness - pointerSize;
        RoundRectangle2D.Double bubble = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(
                0 + strokePad,
                0 + strokePad,
                width - thickness,
                bottomLineY,
                radii,
                radii);
        Polygon pointer = new Polygon();
        if (left) {
            // left point
            pointer.addPoint(
                    strokePad + radii + pointerPad,
                    bottomLineY);
            // right point
            pointer.addPoint(
                    strokePad + radii + pointerPad + pointerSize,
                    bottomLineY);
            // bottom point
            pointer.addPoint(
                    strokePad + radii + pointerPad + (pointerSize / 2),
                    height - strokePad);
        } else {
            // left point
            pointer.addPoint(
                    width - (strokePad + radii + pointerPad),
                    bottomLineY);
            // right point
            pointer.addPoint(
                    width - (strokePad + radii + pointerPad + pointerSize),
                    bottomLineY);
            // bottom point
            pointer.addPoint(
                    width - (strokePad + radii + pointerPad + (pointerSize / 2)),
                    height - strokePad);
        }
        Area area = new Area(bubble);
        area.add(new Area(pointer));
        g2.setRenderingHints(hints);
        // Paint the BG color of the parent, everywhere outside the clip
        // of the text bubble.
        Component parent = c.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            Color bg = parent.getBackground();
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
            Area borderRegion = new Area(rect);
            borderRegion.subtract(area);
            g2.setClip(borderRegion);
            g2.setColor(bg);
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            g2.setClip(null);
        }
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.setStroke(stroke);
        g2.draw(area);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is this link to image i have captured !! if we use msgboxes of different sizes in box layout they have distorted alignment. I think i will have to change my layout manager. But if you have any other suggestion please let me know !!! Thank You for your help . https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2FlsxAUHToXSlJJMFJYY2w5Vmc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: please see my comment under pictures in my answer, have to use constants (dymanically manage with alingment) in used LayoutManager, if there aren't any or doesn't works corretly, then to use another LayoutManager :-)

Comment: apologies i think i was not that clear in my question. I want to do two things. First , like any chat applications msgboxes are supposed to stick with the edges. Second , if we have large text and variable size of msgbox that can change while re-sizing main frame it has to wrap up text in it.

Comment: can vertical or horizontal glue solve my problem of sticking with edges ?? just curious.

Comment: 1. use only JLabels instead of JPanels (in ChatPaneMsgBox) 2. to change JPanels default LayoutManaget to another (FLowLayout), 3. FlowLayout has constant LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT, overload constructor with this params too, that it, only about decision

Comment: Thanks 2nd option of flowlayout worked like a charm. Thanks a lot !! But i didn't get your 1st sugesstion. I think i might need JPanel for images & other stuff , so i prefer to keep them. If my decision is wrong please let me know! :-)

Comment: there is extend JPanel, to JLabel, and then to remove JLabel as child

Answer (score 1):

Interchange values of **jl.setAlignmentX(0) 0 to 1 and 1 to 0** .in msgbox or ChatPaneMsgBox classes which are given here. Like

```
      if (ij) {
              this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
              //rest code
              jl.setAlignmentX(1); 
              //rest code here
              }
       else   {
               this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.Right));
              //rest code
              jl.setAlignmentX(0); 
              //rest code here
              }
```

even i think now jl.setAlignmentX(); doesn't matter anymore.

Thanks a lot to @mKorbel & @kleopatra for their help & suggestions. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The GridbagLayoutManager does a good job of helping to keep rectangular layouts easy to manage in terms of width and auto sizing.  The programming mechanisms of GridbagLayout are data intensive and this causes many people to run away from it.

Back in 1996, I created the Packer class that is on Java.net under the Packer project.  It wraps GridbagLayoutManager in a subclass which creates and uses GridbagLayout data items to make things work.

To create a simple layout like this, you just need to do something like the following.

```
class MsgObject extends JPanel {
    public MsgObject(String text) {
        Packer pk = new Packer( this );
        pk.pack( new JLabel("<html><body>"+text+"</body></html>") ).fillBoth();
    }
}
class TheirMsgObject extends MsgObject {
    public TheirMsgObject( string text ) {
        super(text);
        setBackground( new Color( 255, 220, 230 ) );
    }
}
class MyMsgObject extends MsgObject {
    public MyMsgObject( string text ) {
        super(text);
        setBackground( new Color( 220, 230, 255 ) );
    }
}
class MsgPane extends JPanel {
    int items = -1;
    Packer mpk;
    BlankSpace = blank;
    class BlankSpace extends JPanel {
        public Dimension PreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension( 100, 2 );
        }
    }
    public void MsgPane() {
        mpk = new Packer( this);
        blank = new BlankSpace();
    }

    private void addMessage( MsgObject msg, int col ) {
        mpk.pack( msg ).gridx(0).gridy(++items).gridw(col).fillx(1);
    }
    public void addMessage( TheirMsgObject msg ) {
        addMessage( msg, 0 );
    }

    public void addMessage( MyMsgObject msg ) {
        addMessage( msg, 1 );
        mpk.pack( blank ).gridx(0).gridy(items);
    }
}
```

Then, you can create the appropriate MsgObject and just add it to the container and it will appear there.  You can add appropriate code for scrolling on add etc.