# How to set padding at JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I want to display a Multiline JLabel into JPanel.
So I have this code but I'm not able to show the multiline JLabel.

```
public class NotificationFrame extends JFrame{
    public NotificationFrame(){
        JPanel panelBody = new JPanel();
        panelBody.setBackground(Color.white);
        GridBagConstraints GBC2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        Container CR2 = new Container();
        GridBagLayout GBL2 = new GridBagLayout();
        CR2.setLayout(GBL2);     
        panelBody.add(CR2);

        GBC2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        CR2.add(labelTesto);
        GBC2.gridx=0;
        GBC2.gridy=0;
        GBC2.insets.left = 10;
        GBC2.insets.top=0;
        GBL2.setConstraints(labelTesto,GBC2);
        panelBody.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER)); 


        add(panelBody,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

If I change the last line of code in

```
add(labelTest,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I can show that I want. But it is not correct because I want to set a padding on JLabel

> EDIT

I have use this code now:

```
JPanel panelBody = new JPanel();
panelBody.setBackground(Color.white);
SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
panelBody.setLayout(layout);
panelBody.add(labelTesto);
layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, labelTesto, 15, SpringLayout.NORTH, panelBody);
add(panelBody,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This is the layout:

[image]

This is the all test that I should see: 
"Il 31 Dicembre scadrà l'assistenza, ricorda di rinnovare l'assistenza per ricevere sempre assistenza ed aggiornamenti."

Comment: For best help: Post an image of what you desire and one of what you're getting, and create and post an [mcve].

Comment: I've never seen `new Container()` in code before.  I suggest you change it to `new JPanel()`.

Comment: *"I want to set a padding on JLabel"*  Add an `EmptyBorder` to the label.  But for a good chance of things better than that comment, follow the sage advice of @HovercraftFullOfEels ..

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Follow Java conventions when posting code.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Multiline it's not padding. For achieve multiline text in JLabel or JButton you need to use HTML.

To wrap text (or multiline):

```
btn.setText("<html><p>Il 31 Dicembre scadrà l'assistenza, ricorda di rinnovare l'assistenza per ricevere sempre assistenza ed aggiornamenti</p></html>");
label.setText("<html>Date:<br></html>"+getDateFromSomeWhere);
```

To set padding:

```
    label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,10,0,0));//top,left,bottom,right
```

Comment: It worked, Now I want to give some border with Rounded corners, how can we do it

Comment: There are plenty of examples over internet. [This is one of them.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025092/border-with-rounded-corners-transparency)