# JTextArea Rounded Corners

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, rounded-corners

I want to make JTextArea has a rounded corners, and i did this code :

```
public BPosTxtArea() {
    super();
    setOpaque(false);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setColor(getBackground());
    g2.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 15, 15);
    super.paintComponent(g);
}

@Override
protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setColor(new Color(102, 102, 102));
    g2.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 15, 15);
}
```

but it still has a square border outside like picture bellow :

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you add the text area to a JScrollPane? Maybe you are seeing the Border of the scroll pane. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: No i just want it has rounded corners

Comment: *"i just want it has rounded corners"* Just post a [mcve] or SSCCE.  Voting to close.

Comment: Duplicate of [Border with rounded corners & transparency](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15025092/418556).  (Someone else will need to close it, given I added, then retracted a prior close vote, I cannot close it.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start by having a look at [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)

This is a very simple example:

```
public class RoundBorder implements Border {

    private int radius;

    public RoundBorder(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, width - 1, height - 1, getRadius(), getRadius()));
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        int value = getRadius() / 2;
        return new Insets(value, value, value, value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

[image: Rounded Border]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }

    public Example() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            ta.setBorder(new RoundBorder(20));

            JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(10, 20));
            sp.setBorder(new RoundBorder(20));

            add(ta, gbc);
            add(sp, gbc);
        }

    }

    public class RoundBorder implements Border {

        private int radius;

        public RoundBorder(int radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, width - 1, height - 1, getRadius(), getRadius()));
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
            int value = getRadius() / 2;
            return new Insets(value, value, value, value);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Problems, the border is painted "within" the component fill area, meaning that the corners will be the same color as the fill area. There's no way around it using `Border`.

The trick would be to create a second component, onto which you could paint the border (via the `paintComponent`, filling the area within the border the same color as the text area) and then add the component into that.

**Updated**

Based on you code example, you're not overriding `getInsets`, which is going to be very important, the other thing is, it appears that your `JTextArea` is within a `JScrollPane`...

[image: Comparison]

```
public class BPosTextArea extends JTextArea {

    private int radius;

    public BPosTextArea() {
        super(10, 20);
        setOpaque(false);
        setBorder(null);
        setRadius(20);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(getBackground());
        g2.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, getRadius(), getRadius());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(new Color(102, 102, 102));
        g2.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, getRadius(), getRadius());
    }

    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
        repaint();
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getInsets() {
        int value = getRadius() / 2;
        return new Insets(value, value, value, value);
    }

}
```

A solution is to set the `border` to `null` for the `JScrollPane`

Comment: I did `setBorder` to null and overriding method `getInsets` but there's no change. Is there any other way to remove `JScrollPane` ?

Comment: You don't want to remove the `JScrollPane`, setting the `JScrollPane`'s `border` to `null` "should" remove it. You may also need to make the `JScrollPane`'s `JViewport` transparent as well as the `JScrollPane` itself

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, the detail is that JTextArea is linked to a JScrollPane which is adding that border to your TextArea, I corrected it this way. You must check what scrollpane is linked to once identified in the constructor of your class you must add this.

```
 jScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
```

and your textarea will look like this:

[image: example]

You can give more style to your scroll but that is already separate.