# Border for undecorated JFrame with curve corners

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I have  a JFrame which already have undecorated and made the corners curve as in the
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83szi.jpg).

I want to apply a border for this JFrame. For that I have tried with following code.

```
getRootPane().setBorder( BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY) );
```

This Code applies the borders only for the edges without including the corners. So How can I apply the border for the corners also?

Comment: Curved corners are a waste of screen acreage. What is the designer afraid of, that someone will cut themselves on the sharp corner? My advice is to use that effort on making the content of the frame stylish, logical and 'path of least surprise'. The end user will appreciate that more. Rounded corners are unnecessary futzing.

Comment: see  [Border with rounded corners & transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025092/border-with-rounded-corners-transparency)