# Rounded LineBorder - not all corners are rounded

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jfreechart, java-10

I'm using `JFreeChart` and I want to customise the `ToolTip` by creating my own `Class` which extends `ChartPanel` and override `createToolTip()`.

```
static private class PrivateChartPanel extends ChartPanel{

    //constructors

    @Override
    public JToolTip createToolTip() {

        JToolTip jtt = super.createToolTip();

        jtt.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        jtt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1, true));

        return jtt;

    }

}
```

The problem is at `Border`. It is not rounded on all corners.

[image: tooltip-border-problem]

Why it is not rounded on all corners and how I could done it?

P.S.: I created a new simple project

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class HelloWorld {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame a = new JFrame();

    a.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
    a.setLayout(null);

    JPanel b = new JPanel();

    b.setBounds(5, 5, 50, 50);
    b.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1, true));

    a.add(b);

    a.setVisible(true);

  }

}
```

and Border of JPanel is with same problem. I'm using `Java 10`

Comment: Does maybe the ChartPanel override the Border? Have you tried using the Border on other components?

Comment: @camickr I don't know what to say about `@Override Border`. I use `BorderFactory` from `javax.swing`. But I created a new simple project with [this 
 code](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tpcg.php?p=s4hlHj) and `Border` of `JPanel` is with same problem. P.S.: I use `Java10`.

Comment: Post your code that demonstrates the problem in your question. Then we can copy/paste to see if we have the same problem or whether this could be a version/platform problem.

Comment: @camickr [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tpcg.php?p=s4hlHj) is a sample which has the same problem, for me.

Comment: The code should be posted with your question, not on another website.

Comment: @camickr now is ok?

Comment: It doesn't work for me either using JDK8 on Windows 7. You can try creating your own Border. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025092/border-with-rounded-corners-transparency

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Border with rounded corners & transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025092/border-with-rounded-corners-transparency)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The effect of rounded corners depends on the size of these rounded corners. In case of `LineBorder`, it is determined by the `thickness` property. This is how the relevant implementation code looks like:

```
int offs = this.thickness;
int size = offs + offs;
if (this.roundedCorners) {
    float arc = .2f * offs;
    outer = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height, offs, offs);
    inner = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(x + offs, y + offs, width - size, height - size, arc, arc);
}
else {
    outer = new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
    inner = new Rectangle2D.Float(x + offs, y + offs, width - size, height - size);
}
Path2D path = new Path2D.Float(Path2D.WIND_EVEN_ODD);
path.append(outer, false);
path.append(inner, false);
g2d.fill(path);
```

So it differentiates between inner and outer corner, which is not much meaningful for a line size of one. But even worse, the outer corner size is just `offs`, which is identical to `thickness` (one in your case) and the size of the inner rounded corner is determined by `arc`, which is `.2f * offs`. For your `thickness` of one, the resulting inner corner size is `0.2`. So it seems to be a pure coincidence (rounding issue of these two different corners) that we see an effect in the upper left corner, as even the bigger outer corner size of one is not enough to create a visible rounded effect.

Here is how it looks like with a `thickness` of `20`, which results in an outer corner size of `20` and a whopping inner corner size of `4`:

[image: Screenshot with border thickness of 20]

It don’t know which actual use case the Swing developers had in mind when they added the rounded corner support in this class. I can’t imagine any scenario where this strategy is useful.

Implementing a meaningful `Border` is not that hard. One possible implementation looks like:

```
public class RoundedLineBorder extends AbstractBorder {
    int lineSize, cornerSize;
    Paint fill;
    Stroke stroke;
    private Object aaHint;

    public RoundedLineBorder(Paint fill, int lineSize, int cornerSize) {
        this.fill = fill;
        this.lineSize = lineSize;
        this.cornerSize = cornerSize;
        stroke = new BasicStroke(lineSize);
    }
    public RoundedLineBorder(Paint fill, int lineSize, int cornerSize, boolean antiAlias) {
        this.fill = fill;
        this.lineSize = lineSize;
        this.cornerSize = cornerSize;
        stroke = new BasicStroke(lineSize);
        aaHint = antiAlias? RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON: RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF;
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets) {
        int size = Math.max(lineSize, cornerSize);
        if(insets == null) insets = new Insets(size, size, size, size);
        else insets.left = insets.top = insets.right = insets.bottom = size;
        return insets;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        Paint oldPaint = g2d.getPaint();
        Stroke oldStroke = g2d.getStroke();
        Object oldAA = g2d.getRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING);
        try {
            g2d.setPaint(fill!=null? fill: c.getForeground());
            g2d.setStroke(stroke);
            if(aaHint != null) g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, aaHint);
            int off = lineSize >> 1;
            g2d.drawRoundRect(x+off, y+off, width-lineSize, height-lineSize, cornerSize, cornerSize);
        }
        finally {
            g2d.setPaint(oldPaint);
            g2d.setStroke(oldStroke);
            if(aaHint != null) g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, oldAA);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I change the line

```
b.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1, true));
```

in your example to

```
b.setBorder(new RoundedLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1, 10, true));
```

I get

[image: Screenshot with custom border]