# Using TextBubbleBorder in a popup

Tags: java, swing, border

First of all many thanks to Andrew Thompson for his [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025092/border-with-rounded-corners-transparency) about border with rounded corners.

Now my problem. I try to add the "What's new" feature in our application (small bubble which points the new component). All works fine except the transparency feature of the border. Here is my MCVE (sorry it's a little bit long, because it contains the code written by Andrew).

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.Popup;
import javax.swing.PopupFactory;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;

/**
 * <code>PopupTryout</code>.
 */
public class PopupTryout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Popup test");
        JButton button = new JButton("Test");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(button);
        frm.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frm.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea()));
        JPanel hintPanel = new JPanel();
        hintPanel.add(new JLabel("This button has no function ;)"));
        hintPanel.setOpaque(false);
        JLabel closeBtn = new JLabel("Close");
        closeBtn.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        closeBtn.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        hintPanel.add(closeBtn);
        hintPanel.setBorder(new TextBubbleBorder(Color.BLACK, 1, 6, 8, false));

        frm.setSize(600, 500);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        Point pt = button.getLocationOnScreen();
        Dimension panelSize = hintPanel.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension buttonSize = button.getSize();
        int x = pt.x + buttonSize.width - panelSize.width;
        int y = pt.y - panelSize.height - 10;
        // popup should only be closed when user clicks the "Close" button.
        Popup popup = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(button, hintPanel, x, y);
        popup.show();
        // "link style" button
        closeBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                Font f = e.getComponent().getFont();
                e.getComponent().setFont(underlineOn(f));
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                e.getComponent().setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font"));
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                popup.hide();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Gets the underline font for the given base font.
     * 
     * @param aBaseFont base font to paint it as underline.
     * @return underline font.
     */
    public static Font underlineOn(Font aBaseFont) {
        return aBaseFont.deriveFont(Collections.singletonMap(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON));
    }

    static class TextBubbleBorder extends AbstractBorder {

        private Color color;

        private int thickness = 4;

        private int radii = 8;

        private int pointerSize = 7;

        private Insets insets = null;

        private BasicStroke stroke = null;

        private int strokePad;

        private int pointerPad = 4;

        private boolean left = true;

        RenderingHints hints;

        TextBubbleBorder(Color color) {
            this(color, 4, 8, 7);
        }

        TextBubbleBorder(Color color, int thickness, int radii, int pointerSize) {
            this.thickness = thickness;
            this.radii = radii;
            this.pointerSize = pointerSize;
            this.color = color;

            stroke = new BasicStroke(thickness);
            strokePad = thickness / 2;

            hints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            int pad = radii + strokePad;
            int bottomPad = pad + pointerSize + strokePad;
            insets = new Insets(pad, pad, bottomPad, pad);
        }

        TextBubbleBorder(Color color, int thickness, int radii, int pointerSize, boolean left) {
            this(color, thickness, radii, pointerSize);
            this.left = left;
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
            return insets;
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets) {
            return getBorderInsets(c);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            int bottomLineY = height - thickness - pointerSize;

            RoundRectangle2D.Double bubble =
                    new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0 + strokePad, 0 + strokePad, width - thickness, bottomLineY, radii, radii);

            Polygon pointer = new Polygon();

            if (left) {
                // left point
                pointer.addPoint(strokePad + radii + pointerPad, bottomLineY);
                // right point
                pointer.addPoint(strokePad + radii + pointerPad + pointerSize, bottomLineY);
                // bottom point
                pointer.addPoint(strokePad + radii + pointerPad + (pointerSize / 2), height - strokePad);
            } else {
                // left point
                pointer.addPoint(width - (strokePad + radii + pointerPad), bottomLineY);
                // right point
                pointer.addPoint(width - (strokePad + radii + pointerPad + pointerSize), bottomLineY);
                // bottom point
                pointer.addPoint(width - (strokePad + radii + pointerPad + (pointerSize / 2)), height - strokePad);
            }

            Area area = new Area(bubble);
            area.add(new Area(pointer));

            g2.setRenderingHints(hints);

            // Paint the BG color of the parent, everywhere outside the clip
            // of the text bubble.
            Component parent = c.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                Color bg = parent.getBackground();
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
                Area borderRegion = new Area(rect);
                borderRegion.subtract(area);
                g2.setClip(borderRegion);
                g2.setColor(bg);
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
                g2.setClip(null);
            }

            g2.setColor(color);
            g2.setStroke(stroke);
            g2.draw(area);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result which I've got
[image]

As you can see, the bottom part of the popup is not transparent. I understand why it so (the initial solution is not suitable for this case), but can't find a solution to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: *"sorry it's a little bit long"* 206 LOC is not **that** long! I haven't got the time to look into this ATM, so hopefully someone else will take it up soon.

Comment: An easy way to compact java code is to use bulk imports, as java.awt.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Translucent and Shaped Swing Windows | Java.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20150515015137/http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/03/18/translucent-and-shaped-swing-windows.html). May be it helps.

```
// Add Popup to a transparent JWindow to create and display.
PopupFactory.setSharedInstance(new TranslucentPopupFactory());

// popup should only be closed when user clicks the "Close" button.
Popup popup = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(button, hintPanel, x, y);
```

**PopupTryout2.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;

public class PopupTryout2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frm = new JFrame("Popup test");
    JButton button = new JButton("Test");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(button);
    frm.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frm.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea()));

    JPanel hintPanel = new JPanel();
    hintPanel.add(new JLabel("This button has no function ;)"));
    hintPanel.setOpaque(false);
    JLabel closeBtn = new JLabel("Close");
    closeBtn.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    closeBtn.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    hintPanel.add(closeBtn);
    hintPanel.setBorder(new TextBubbleBorder(Color.BLACK, 1, 6, 8, false));
    hintPanel.setOpaque(false);

    frm.setSize(600, 500);
    frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frm.setVisible(true);
    Point pt = button.getLocationOnScreen();
    Dimension panelSize = hintPanel.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension buttonSize = button.getSize();
    int x = pt.x + buttonSize.width - panelSize.width;
    int y = pt.y - panelSize.height - 10;

    PopupFactory.setSharedInstance(new TranslucentPopupFactory());

    // popup should only be closed when user clicks the "Close" button.
    Popup popup = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(button, hintPanel, x, y);

    popup.show();
    // "link style" button
    closeBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        Font f = e.getComponent().getFont();
        e.getComponent().setFont(underlineOn(f));
      }

      @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        e.getComponent().setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font"));
      }

      @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        popup.hide();
      }
    });
  }

  public static Font underlineOn(Font aBaseFont) {
    return aBaseFont.deriveFont(Collections.singletonMap(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON));
  }

  static class TextBubbleBorder extends AbstractBorder {
    private Color color;
    private int thickness = 4;
    private int radii = 8;
    private int pointerSize = 7;
    private Insets insets = null;
    private BasicStroke stroke = null;
    private int strokePad;
    private int pointerPad = 4;
    private boolean left = true;
    RenderingHints hints;

    TextBubbleBorder(Color color) {
      this(color, 4, 8, 7);
    }

    TextBubbleBorder(Color color, int thickness, int radii, int pointerSize) {
      this.thickness = thickness;
      this.radii = radii;
      this.pointerSize = pointerSize;
      this.color = color;

      stroke = new BasicStroke(thickness);
      strokePad = thickness / 2;

      hints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

      int pad = radii + strokePad;
      int bottomPad = pad + pointerSize + strokePad;
      insets = new Insets(pad, pad, bottomPad, pad);
    }

    TextBubbleBorder(Color color, int thickness, int radii, int pointerSize, boolean left) {
      this(color, thickness, radii, pointerSize);
      this.left = left;
    }

    @Override public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
      return insets;
    }

    @Override public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets) {
      return getBorderInsets(c);
    }

    @Override public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      int bottomLineY = height - thickness - pointerSize;
      RoundRectangle2D.Double bubble =
        new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0 + strokePad, 0 + strokePad, width - thickness, bottomLineY, radii, radii);

      Polygon pointer = new Polygon();

      if (left) {
        pointer.addPoint(strokePad + radii + pointerPad, bottomLineY);
        pointer.addPoint(strokePad + radii + pointerPad + pointerSize, bottomLineY);
        pointer.addPoint(strokePad + radii + pointerPad + (pointerSize / 2), height - strokePad);
      } else {
        pointer.addPoint(width - (strokePad + radii + pointerPad), bottomLineY);
        pointer.addPoint(width - (strokePad + radii + pointerPad + pointerSize), bottomLineY);
        pointer.addPoint(width - (strokePad + radii + pointerPad + (pointerSize / 2)), height - strokePad);
      }

      Area area = new Area(bubble);
      area.add(new Area(pointer));

      g2.setRenderingHints(hints);

      // Paint the BG color of the parent, everywhere outside the clip
      // of the text bubble.
      Component parent = c.getParent();
      if (parent != null) {
        Color bg = parent.getBackground();
        // Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        // Area borderRegion = new Area(rect);
        // borderRegion.subtract(area);
        // g2.setClip(borderRegion);
        // g2.setColor(bg);
        // g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        // g2.setClip(null);
        g2.setPaint(bg);
        g2.fill(area);
      }
      g2.setColor(color);
      g2.setStroke(stroke);
      g2.draw(area);
    }
  }
}

/*
@see http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/03/18/translucent-and-shaped-swing-windows.html
https://web.archive.org/web/20150515015137/http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/03/18/translucent-and-shaped-swing-windows.html
Translucent and Shaped Swing Windows | Java.net
*/
class TranslucentPopupFactory extends PopupFactory {
  @Override public Popup getPopup(Component owner, Component contents, int x, int y) {
    return new TranslucentPopup(owner, contents, x, y);
  }
}

class TranslucentPopup extends Popup {
  private final JWindow popupWindow;

  protected TranslucentPopup(Component owner, Component contents, int ownerX, int ownerY) {
    super(owner, contents, ownerX, ownerY);
    // create a new heavyweight window
    this.popupWindow = new JWindow();
    // mark the popup with partial opacity
    // AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(popupWindow, (contents instanceof JToolTip) ? .8f : .95f);
    // popupWindow.setOpacity(.5f);
    // AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(popupWindow, false); // Java 1.6.0_10
    popupWindow.setBackground(new Color(0x0, true)); // Java 1.7.0
    // determine the popup location
    popupWindow.setLocation(ownerX, ownerY);
    // add the contents to the popup
    popupWindow.getContentPane().add(contents);
    contents.invalidate();
    // JComponent parent = (JComponent) contents.getParent();
    // set the shadow border
    // parent.setBorder(new ShadowPopupBorder());
  }

  @Override public void show() {
    System.out.println("Always Heavy weight!");
    this.popupWindow.setVisible(true);
    this.popupWindow.pack();
    // mark the window as non-opaque, so that the
    // shadow border pixels take on the per-pixel
    // translucency
    // AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this.popupWindow, false);
  }

  @Override public void hide() {
    this.popupWindow.setVisible(false);
    this.popupWindow.removeAll();
    this.popupWindow.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and upvote. It's good idea. I will check whether it works for me.

Comment: Works fine. Only one question: how can I change background of the hint? When I make the hintPanel opaque and set the color I get the same problem again :(.

Comment: Problem solved. I simply need to change the background for content pane of the popupWindow.