# How to place a jframe above a fullscreen window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, frame, fullscreen

I wanted to create an autoclicker that should have different functions. This autoclicker should have a JFrame in which you can make some configurations. I also wanted to offer a way to place the window "up". It should be possible to place the windows in a corner and it should also stay at the top when you are in a full screen. For example, if I am in a game, I want to be able to play the game as normal. While I'm playing the JFrame should stay above the game so I can see autoclickerframe. When I click on the window on which I can make settings, this should happen without the fullscreen window is reduced.

So my question is how this would be possible. I have seen "overlays" like this often already. Isn't overwolfs layout also working like my frame should? Is this even possible with java, if yes may one tell me how?

Comment: For an autoclicker, you should avoid creating a JFrame as it will block the application that you are trying to click onto. Research about the Robot class in java which is used for UI testing. You can navigate to screen coordinates and click using this class.

Comment: No thats not my problem. The autoclicker does not only click left and rightclick but also every key one configure. My only problem is that I want the frame above a fullscreen window. But the fullscreenwindow and the frame should not conflict each other.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you don't need a window. A simple java console program can click on any coordinate even when it is running in the background.

Comment: I know this but i want a window so it can show which buttons gets clicked and that one is able to configure it while using it. My plan is that in the moment you click on the frame the autoclicker deactivates and you can configure which buttons should click when one click on the fullscreen window again the autoclicker activates again.
But thats not the point I just want that frame beeing above an fullscreen. This code could also be used for other things.

Comment: Probably [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55118808/using-textbubbleborder-in-a-popup) helps you to find a solution.

Comment: So when i saw the post @SergiyMedvynskyy linked right, it is only about popups. But what i need is how u place a frame above a fullscreen window so one can still use both.