# How do you print a horizontal line on an image and add "thickness"?

Tags: java

So I have the code to print a horizontal line on an image...

```
public void printH_line(int row, int thickness, int red, int green, int blue) {
    Pixel[] pixels = pic.getPixels();
    System.out.println("\nprintH_line");

    for (int c = 0; c < 200; c++) {
        Pixel pix = pic.getPixel(c, row);
        pix.setColor(new Color(limitVal(red), limitVal(green),
                limitVal(blue)));
```

Now I just don't know how to do the "thickness," meaning how thick the user wants the line to be.  I will be asking the user to enter a number on how thick they want the line to be and that is "int thickness."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to print a line x number of times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290886/java-how-to-print-a-line-x-number-of-times)

Comment: Draw a rectangle instead.

Comment: I can't tell what API you are using. I don't see any Graphics methods being used. Also, why would you create a new Color every time through the loop. It looks to me like you are creating the same Color.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Graphics2D.setStroke(Stroke)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setStroke%28java.awt.Stroke%29) as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8463742/418556).

[image]