# Draw button border with gradient color

Tags: java, swing, border, jbutton, gradient

I want to draw a button border like this with gradient color at border of rounded button (the red one):

[image]

Does anybody know some Java class that can do this?

Comment: Try adapting [`TextBubbleBorder`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8463742/418556)..

Answer (score 3):

You can create your custom Button class by extending JButton. Then you have to rewrite the paintComponent(Grapgics g) mehtod to draw your button like you want.

Comment: Yes, I know i gotta do that. but the things is how can we draw the gradient border as i want. I don't know what i should do with Graphics2D g2 to draw that border

Comment: *"I don't know what i should do with Graphics2D"*  Umm.. look at the `paintBorder` method of `TextBubbleBorder`..